# iPhone adding events in calendar

Tags: iphone

Why is my Add Event plus sign gray and disabled? The calendar, add event plus sign should be red. This is usually top right like in the picture I added.

[image]

I tried refreshing and swiping down in the Show All Calendars. Hiding or closing did not work. I also tried switching iCloud on. These tasks are only a precursor to be able to add events again.

Until I realised that I had to reestablish or open a new Calendar because I had deleted it by not wanting iCloud anymore, a few minutes in frustration had passed. Adding my own Calendar again was my solution!!

Comment: Hey and welcome! It is unclear what you're asking. Is the problem solved? I don't see a greyed + sign either!

Comment: Please wort this so the answer goes on the answer section and the question is just a question. We don’t host blog posts, but it’s totally expected if you answer your own question.